# How to make a chatbot recognise answers in both lower and uppercase

Tags: python

I am trying to make my python chat bot recognise the answers i have given to it in both upper and lowercase.
Here is one of the questions in my code.
(all of the code is written in the format you see below)

```
 Q1 = input ("If you could have any pet what would it be?")
 if Q1 == "hamster":
     print ("I would love a pet hamster")
 elif Q1 in "dog,cat,rabbit,gerbil,fish,rat":
     print ("Not my first choice, but still good!")
 else:
     print ("Not bad.")
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: so make this Q1 = input ("If you could have any pet what would it be?") look like this Q1 = Q1.lower()input ("If you could have any pet what would it be?")

Comment: noo... at that point `Q1` does not exists. Do it after the `input(..)`.

Comment: so like this? Q1 = Q1.lower("If you could have any pet what would it be?")input

Comment: or like Q1 = Q1.lower("If you could have any pet what would it be?") without input

Comment: Nooo... first line is `Q1 = input('blablabla')`, second one `Q1 = Q1.lower()`.

Comment: so line 2 would look like  if Q1 = Q1.lower("hamster")

Comment: no, without an argument. You convert what the user has written to the equivalent in lowercase. So if the user wrote `'HaMsTeR`, then after `Q1 = Q1.lower()`, `Q1` will be `'hamster'`. So we pretend like the user already wrote it in lowercase.

Comment: i really dont understand where im supposed to put the changed code sorry

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
Q1 = input ("If you could have any pet what would it be?")
```

to be:

```
Q1 = input("If you could have any pet what would it be?").lower()
```

---

It should be noted that this:

```
if Q1 in "dog,cat,rabbit,gerbil,fish,rat":`
```

is pretty strange, and should probably be

```
if Q1 in {"dog", "cat", "rabbit", "gerbil", "fish", "rat"}:
```

otherwise, `dog,cat,rabbit` would be a valid pet.